# Automatically Pass A Value to an Input Prompt from a Windows Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a window scheduled task that run a batch file which triggers another batch and pass a value to the input prompt during the run. I thought that I could simply `set` a variable and the `echo` it to pass the value but this didn't work.  How do I automatically pass a variable to a input prompt?
I have executed the script below but it is stuck at "User: ".

```
@echo on
SET USER=S444555
FTPS.exe -a -z -e:on -d -pfxfile:"S132456.p12" -pfxpwfile:"132456.p12.pwd" -z ftps.domain.net 2121
echo %USER%
```

Comment: this question is off topic here as it is not programming related, besides that, echo will echo to the cmd, not the external ftps.exe command, there are other method to do this.

Comment: What about using a pipe, like `echo %USER%| FTPS.exe ...`? see [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)...